# Why does Bernoulli's principle say higher water velocity is at a lower pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity, flow, bernoulli-equation

I'm reading [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/fluids/fluid-dynamics/a/what-is-bernoullis-equation) which says in this picture:

[image]

That `P1 > P2` since `P1`'s positive work is greater than `P2`'s negative work. However, I thought forces do work, not pressures. Since `F = P * A`, I only understand why `P1 * A1 > P2 * A2`. You can even see in the picture that `A1` is greater than `A2`. How come we can confidently say `P1 > P2` then?

Comment: The question you are asking is literally right there on the page in the hidden insert that opens up if you clicked ``[Wait, does that really follow?]". In particular, you have to consider not just F = P A, but rather also note that A v = const

Comment: @naturallyinconsistent Ah, can't believe I missed that! Thank you, I'll accept if you post that as an answer.

Comment: It is ok, I'd get flagged as ``this should be a comment" if I tried to make it a full post. Anyway, the essential takeaway of Bernoulli is that PV is an energy, KE is clearly an energy, and GPE is another energy, so their sum should be conserved. Divide by V everywhere, and P + half rho v^2 + rho g h is a conserved energy density.

Answer (score 3):

First of all look at the conservation of mass in this example, equation of continuity,  $A_1\rho_1v_1 = A_2\rho_2v_2 $ assume that the density of the fluid $\rho$ stays constant.
$A_1>A_2 \Rightarrow V_2>v_1$, thus the kinetic energy of the fluid increases when the area decreases.
How is the increase in kinetic energy achieved?
Net work per second must be done on the fluid by the forces, $P_1A_1$ and $P_2A_2$, exerted on the fluid, ie $P_1\color{red}{A_1v_1} - P_2\color{red}{A_2v_2}\Rightarrow P_1>P_2$

Comment: Isn't work done F.d so it would be P1A1.d and d=velocity*time then we would get the final equation ???

Comment: @NaveenV I have added the words "per second", so $PAv$ is the work done per second.

Comment: Yeah , now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

We can easily see why:

$$P_1+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2=P_2+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2$$

Also,$$A_1v_1=A_2v_2$$

Plugging in value of $v_2$

$$P_1=P_2+\frac{1}{2}\rho\left(\frac{A_1^2}{A_2^2}-1\right)v_1^2$$

Since $A_1>A_2$, second term is positive. So easily we can deduce that $P_1>P_2$